# converting a list with strings into a list with floats

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import csv
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col_one = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter= '\t')]
    plots = col_one[1:]
```

The data in column one are floats, but above code makes list of strings. How can I make the list of floats correcting above codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert string to float using `float()` function

```
import csv
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col_one = [float(row[0]) for index, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f, delimiter= '\t')) if index != 0]
```

Comment: could not get the result since the first row (header) is not float.

Comment: You'd be checking the index every time, where you could just remove the first line and keep the rest (improving performance)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `float` built-in:

```
col = [float(row[0]) for row in rows]
```

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#float